# Functions of sequences and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

(a) If $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and {$x_n$} is a sequence in $(0,\infty)$ such that {$f(x_n)$} diverges to $\infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$.

(b) If $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and {$x_n$} is a sequence in $(0,\infty)$ such that {$f(x_n)$} diverges to $\infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$.

Are the statements true of false? If true, prove. If false, give a counterexample.

I think the first one is false and the second one is true. Can anyone help me to come up with a counterexample for (a) and a proof for (b) please?

Answer (score 2):

(b) is false, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.  Take $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$.
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n=0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=\infty$.

I'm not sure if the proofs of (a) given are complete, since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n\ne\infty$ does not imply $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n<\infty$ or even that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

a) A continuous image of a compact set is compact, hence if $\{f(x_n)\}$ is unbounded, $\{x_n\}$ cannot be bounded.

b) is obviously false. See $f(x)=1/x$.

Hence we cannot prove and disprove what you want to. ;-)

Comment: Oh ok, so I was completely on the wrong track here. Thanks a lot for clarifying! :)

Answer (score 1):

For a) you can think a contradition argument, suppose that $\lim x_n<\infty$, since $x_n\in(0,\infty)$ ther exists $C>0$ such that $0<x_n\leq C$, since $(0,C]\subset[0,C]$ we have that $f([0,C])$ is bounded (because $f$ is continuous), contradiction.